# Embedding Flash in php

Tags: php, flash

I'm using flash to show my charts in the website i have written php file for getting the data from the db,for example say im getting the numbers of males from the db as `$males =1067;`

i'm using this value like this

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="$chartWidth" height="$chartHeight" id="$chartId">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="movie" value="$chartSWF"/>
                <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"opaque\" />
        **<param name="FlashVars" value="$males />**
```

but what is the problem is i'm not getting the exact value of male 1067,
it showing up 1k in my chart of flash how to get the exact value , when i it cross over 1000 it showing as 1k

Comment: Did you program the chart you self? It sounds to me like it's the flash file that converts the number. (Allso, remember to end the value with " on the last line)

Answer (score 1):

Always when ever you embed any php code do it within php tags

and to print it you should `echo` it out

So your code should look like

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="<?php echo $chartWidth; ?>" height="<?php echo $chartHeight; ?>" id="<?php echo $chartId; ?>">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="<?php echo $chartSWF; ?>"/>
            <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"opaque\" />
    **<param name="FlashVars" value="<?php echo $males; ?> />**
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use swfobject for embedded flash.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/